# How to start a roscore at system boot so that nodes run automatically when system is up?

Tags: roslaunch, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a Ubuntu 14.04 system with ROS Indigo. I currently have a python script in the /home/usr path that is launched by a desktop file using auto-start. I use roslaunch inside the python script to bring up other ROS nodes/packages elsewhere in the system using import roslaunch and rospy. I have sourced the ROS package (/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash) in bashrc as well as the other packages I am running through the script. The problem is that when I reboot the system, my python script executes but comes up with the error message "no module named rospy" (or roslaunch). I tried starting a roscore using the subprocess.Popen('roscore') in the python script as well but the error was "No such file". I want to run some operations in the python program before the "roslaunch" operation and all this needs to execute at system boot each time. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

- Sneha

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272203/how-to-start-a-roscore-at-system-boot-so-that-nodes-run-automatically-when-system-is-up?/) by [i_robot_flight](https://answers.ros.org/users/32131/i_robot_flight/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should probably add your autostart desktop file. The issue is likely that the Python script isn't being run from a bash environment that has sourced your .bashrc. Possible fixes: source the relevant workspace setup.bash files earlier in the boot process so that future processes inherit the env. This is done in the [robot_upstart](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstart) package. Easier might be to add an executable bash script (with #!/bin/bash as first line), that first sources the .bashrc, and then executes the Python script, and then put this in your autostart desktop file.

Could also probably get away with a one-liner to execute the Python script... something like `bash -i -c "/home/user/Desktop/run_process.py"`

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [i_robot_flight](https://answers.ros.org/users/32131/i_robot_flight/) on 2017-10-03**:
@jarvisschultz you were completely right. At boot the bash environment had not started the bashrc before this desktop file executed. I modified my script to switch the order. Thank you very much!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-04**:
@i_robot_flight: as @jarvisschultz answered your question, please accept his answer by ticking the checkmark to the left of his answer.